# How do I change the received url in outgoing emails

Tags: email, email-server, hosts-file, smtp-headers

I've got a cheap and cheerful dedicated server from 1and1 that I use to send emails.
The received email header looks like this:

```
Received: from s123456.onlinehome-server.info (s123456.onlinehome-server.info. [82.165.11.111])
```

I'd like that to say

```
Received: from my.awesome.domain (my.awesome.domain. [82.165.11.111])
```

Another answer I've read suggested "making a change to the /etc/hosts file, which looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
82.165.11.111 s123456.onlinehome-server.info s123456
82.165.11.111 s987654.onlinehome.info
```

I'd nervy about adding or changing anything in that file and getting it wrong - do I just need to add

```
82.165.11.111 my.awesome.domain
```

on the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

received headers are written by the receiving MTA based on your HELO and ([forward confirmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS)) reverse DNS

- set your SMTP `HELO` = `my.awesome.domain` by either configuring your system hostname (depends on os and distro how to do this.. */etc/hostname, /etc/sysconfig/hostname, /etc/hosts* ....) OR overriding the autodetection in your MTA software (eg. in postfix main.cf set *myhostname = my.awesome.domain*)
- set your reverse dns to `my.awesome.domain` in your vps control panel (or tell your vps provider to do this for you if there is no control panel where you can do it yourself)
- make sure there is an dns `A` record `my.awesome.domain 82.165.11.111` (this is required for the forward confirmation, otherwise the received line will probably say "Received from unknown[my.awesome.domain]...)

then wait until the TTL of the old rDNS record has expired and try again (in your case 2 hours)

Comment: I'm cool with the last two - how do I change the HELO setting?

Comment: depends on your MTA. many set the HELO to the system hostname by default , so one possibility is to configure the system hostname and let the MTA autodetect. if you're using postfix you can also set 'myhostname' in main.cf